Remove a Web part from SharePoint subsite using power automate
I want to remove web part(New feed and Get started with your site part) mentioned in the attachment from a SharePoint site using Power Automate. How can I do that?

You can remove the web part using Power Automate flow.

Identify the page and specific web part you would like to remove. Get the web part id using this: In the developer tools, look for the data-sp-webpart-instance-id attribute. This attribute contains the GUID of the web part.

In Power Automate flow you can use action Send an HTTP request to SharePoint. Details are as below:



{
  "method": "POST",
  "uri": "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/yoursite/SitePages/yourpage.aspx')/webparts(guid'webpartid')",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
    "IF-MATCH": "*"
  }
}


